# Jenkins TestNG result integration

Tags: testing, jenkins, junit, testng

I have lots of longrunning separate tests, grouped by functionality in suites in some xml files.

```
<suite name="Suite1" thread-count="1" parallel="false" verbose="1">
    <test name="A" preserve-order="true">
        <classes>
            ...
        </classes>
    </test> 
    <test name="B" preserve-order="true">
        <classes>
            ...
        </classes>
    </test> 
</suite>
```

My problem is, I'd like to generate some kind of html/xml result from grouping the results based on their test name / tag. 
For example, I have these tests from A to E, and the result groups woudl be :

- A,B,C
- B,D,E

I know I could create a separate suite for the tasks (A,B,C) but in that case B would execute again in the second suite, which is not desirable since they are long running... So the idea would be to run every test once, but generate combined reports based on their name/tag.

Is there a plugin for this ? Or how could I achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make your own [reporter](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#logging-reporters) which will be generated the expected result.
[The default reporter](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/blob/master/src/main/java/org/testng/reporters/XMLReporter.java) could be a good start.

Comment: Thanks, this would've worked too, but ended up using the JUnitReport ant task, which can merge XMLs and create a specific report summary.